# Docker container on Web App for Containers - run params configuration

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service, azure-container-service

How can I run docker container on Azure Web app with custom docker run parameters?

for example my app starts like this:

```
docker run -d -p 24389:3000 --name dockertest_2 -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=false -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=dockerTest -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e PORT=3000 -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=ce1389f312f45210c378ab5dd90febd111fb6d6c9292d318c00ae073bae browserless/chrome
```

I want to add -e "MAX_CONCURRENT_SESSIONS=10" -e "TOKEN=2cbc5771-38f2-4dcf-8774-50ad51a971b8" to it.

Answer (score 1):

MAX_CONCURRENT_SESSIONS and TOKEN look like environment variables. If that's the case, you can [add them via the Azure Portal](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2017/09/08/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux/#SetEnvVar) or [via Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-custom-docker-image#configure-environment-variables)